How to Subtotal by year and by country in R
I am trying to subtotal net worth for billionaires by country and by year. I can get R to do it for one, but not both (I can either 'group_by' and sum by year or by country). But I cannot figure out how to group by year and then sum (within each year) by country.
I think a function would be the best solution, but I to figure how to get it to work once before I can repeat it into a function.
My data is 23 years (2000 - 2022) with billionaires' wealth from each country.
My raw data looks something like this:
(the data didn't appear as I intended, the first three are column headers, then year, net worth, and country, and repeated.)
Year   net_worth  country
2000       1.2     Brazil
2000       2.1     France
2000       1.2     Japan
2000       1.4     Japan
2000       2.9     Norway
2001       1.7     Argentina
2001       2.2     Argentina
2001       1.0     Belgium
2001       5.4     Germany

What I am looking for is something like this where it combines the countries within each year (like Japan and Argentina):
2000       1.2     Brazil
2000       2.1     France
2000       2.6     Japan
2000       2.9     Norway
2001       3.9     Argentina
2001       1.0     Belgium
2001       5.4     Germany

I have tried subsetting, which I think would work, but I would have to repeat that about 23 times (and I would like this to be replicable in case I get updated data). Currently there are 29,000 lines and do this manually is very time consuming.
I have also tried 'aggregate' but it totals all years together.
Since I can sort it by year, I think I am looking for a function similar to Excel's "at each change in x, sum y" with the added layer of year.
What I would like to do is create the function that says: each time the year changes, sum for each time the country changes.

Using dplyr: summarise(df, net_worth = sum(net_worth), .by = c(Year, country)). Or df %>% group_by(Year, country) %>% summarise(sum = sum(net_worth)).
